# How to fix the infinity loop in my code? I think it skips the second cin so it keeps looping

Tags: c++, loops, c++11

If i the input is not an int, it's going to give a infinite loop, i think it skips the second cin, but i don't know how to fix it.

```
cout << "Number of days : ";
int days;
cin >> days;
while(!cin){
    cout << "Invalid";
    cin >> days;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the Infinity Loop, you can wipe out half the life in the universe.

Comment: When `cin` fails to parse, it is in an error state, and won't work until you clear the error state.  `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore(whatnot)` where "whatnot" is probably the bad data until the end of the line, but may be other stuff if you are streaming in binary or other formatted input.

Comment: @Eljay hmm no you cant (see: [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o))

Answer (score 2):

When `operator>>` fails to parse input, it puts the stream into an error state that you need to explicitly clear before you can read from the stream again, eg:

```
cout << "Number of days : ";
int days;
while (!(cin >> days)) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Invalid";
}
```